# I'm using showGeneralDialog I need to re-render the button based on a boolean value inside the dialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using showGeneralDialog I need to re-render the button based on a boolean value inside the dialog.I tried to use setState but its not updating the dialog. Here is the example code for showGeneralDialog.

```
showGeneralDialog(
    transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2),(){
        setState(() {
          showNext = true;
        });
      });
      return showNext ?
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: new Text(
                          'Try next',)):Container(),
    context: context,
   );
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your builder function with **StatefulBuilder**. Something like this -

```
showGeneralDialog(
   
      var showNext = false;
      return StatefulBuilder( 
      
      builder:(context,setState){
        if(!showNext){
          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2),(){
          setState(() {
            showNext = true;
           });
        }
             return showNext ?
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: new Text(
                          'Try next',)):Container();
        }),
    context: context,
   );
```